# Запрос в postgresql с case

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос, на получение одной строки

```
select * from
(
select case when
not
 exists (select 1
from cast (json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements('[{"id":"10058432","bdate":"04.04.2016"},{"id":"10058433","bdate":"01.01.2015"}]'::json),'bdate') as date)
where json_extract_path_text
        between
        (SELECT create_date from mc_case WHERE closing_step_id = 1)
        and
        (SELECT close_date from mc_case WHERE closing_step_id = 1)

)
then TRUE
else false
END
from cast (json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements('[{"id":"10058432","bdate":"04.04.2016"},{"id":"10058433","bdate":"01.01.2015"}]'::json),'bdate') as date)
group by 1
) cases
where not FALSE;
```

Как добавить к выводу поле, которое бы когда `else false`, выводило дополнительное поле (запрос - который работает уже с полем `id`, где `case` выдал `false`)

Comment: Вот вместо false его и выводите, т.е. просто поставьте на его место, оно выведется

Comment: [42804] ERROR: CASE types character varying and boolean cannot be matched Позиция: 9065  пишет Пробовал уже

Comment: Ну количество полей должно быть одинаковым всегда, раз не дает разнотипные данные выводить, то надо подумать что должно быть когда вы не хотите выводить значение, может NULL